# MySQL - How to fetch all records from two tables with the pagination?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

We have two tables `credit_points` and `debit_points` having `user_id` is reference. Our concern is we want to fetch all the records in a single query order by created_date DESC with limit and offset. Please find the table list and **Output** table.

credit_points

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id  | credit_value |  created_date       |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 111      | 13           | 2020-01-08 10:20:26 |
|  2 | 111      | 11           | 2020-01-09 11:20:23 |
|  3 | 111      | 7            | 2020-01-09 13:25:12 |
|  4 | 111      | 20           | 2020-01-13 12:25:17 |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

debit_points

```
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id  | debit_value  |  created_date       |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 111      | 13           | 2020-01-09 10:20:25 |
|  2 | 111      | 11           | 2020-01-11 11:18:54 |
|  3 | 111      | 15           | 2020-01-14 13:50:24 |
|  4 | 111      | 5            | 2020-01-14 15:23:12 |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Output should be:

```
+----------+--------------+---+------------------------------+
| user_id  | credit_value | debit_value | created_date       |
+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 111      | NULL         | 5           |2020-01-14 15:23:12 |
| 111      | NULL         | 15          |2020-01-14 13:50:24 |
| 111      | 20           | NULL        |2020-01-13 12:25:17 |
| 111      | NULL         | 11          |2020-01-11 11:18:54 |
| 111      | 7            | NULL        |2020-01-09 13:25:12 |
| 111      | 11           | NULL        |2020-01-09 11:20:23 |
| 111      | NULL         | 13          |2020-01-09 10:20:25 |
| 111      | 13           | NULL        |2020-01-08 10:20:26 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+-----+--------------+
```

Query1:

```
SELECT 
   c.user_id, c.credit_value, d.debit_value, d.created_date
FROM credit_points c 
    RIGHT JOIN debit_points d ON(c.user_id=d.user_id)
WHERE c.user_id=111
ORDER BY c.created_date,d.created_date DESC 
limit 20;
```

I know the above query is completely wrong. Please help me to fetch it in the right way.

Query2:

```
SELECT user_id,credit_value, created_date
FROM credit_points where user_id=111
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id,debit_value,created_date
FROM debit_points where user_id=111 ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

The above query(Query2) is working fine but we are unable to fetch the `debit_value` column. Both credit_value and debit_value is coming in one column.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Looks like UNION ALL.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, UNION gives all the data but it's not possible to set the limit and offset. If you know please share the full query about this

Comment: @jarlh Also, how can we make order by created_date descending order?

Comment: Add your UNION ALL attempt to the question, and someone who knows MySQL will probably help you pretty soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the data from both tables into a derived table by using `UNION` and then execute a `SELECT` over it with needed offset:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT user_id, credit_value, NULL AS debit_value, created_date FROM muvi_credit_points
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_id, NULL AS credit_value, debit_value, created_date FROM muvi_debit_points
) t
WHERE user_id = 111
ORDER BY created_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Of course, the filtering by `user_id` could be done into internal `SELECT` statements if needed.